# Problem regarding parcolumns package

Tags: packages, errors, installing, parcolumns

I needed to use [`parcolumns`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns) packages which was not available on my system. I installed it and now am having some trouble. I followed following steps:

- Locate the package `sauerj` [on CTAN website](http://ctan.org/pkg/sauerj). I [downloaded
  the zip](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sauerj.zip), extracted the folder `sauerj` and ran following command for
  each `.ins` file in the folder: `latex filename.ins`  which created
  `.sty` files in the same directory.
- Copy the entire directory to `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex`
  and `cd` to that directory.
- I ran following commands in that directory: `sudo mktexlsr`, `texhash`.

Now I try to compile a simple code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,20pt]{article}

\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in}, top=1.2in, left=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\pagestyle{fancy}
```

I get following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `processkv.sty' not found.
```

If I remove `\usepackage{parcolumns}` line, the script works.
But I need to use `parcolumns` package.

BTW, the [`sauerj.zip`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sauerj.zip) had files related to [`processkv`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/processkv).

Comment: does the directory you added via mktexlsr contain `processkv.sty` which should have been extracted from `processkv.dtx` by running tex on `processkv.ins`. If it isn't there there was a problem with the extraction, if it is there but tex didn't find it there was a problem with tex directory searching.

Comment: Are you using TeX Live? If so, using its package manager [`tlmgr`](http://tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html) to install `parcolumns` is better than doing this by hand as it resolves dependencies and updates files automatically if necessary. All you need to do is invoking `sudo tlmgr install sauerj`.

Comment: this question talks about `parcolumns` but the error is actually to do with updating your packages. run `tlmgr update --self --all` and you should be set; installing packages manually is a pretty tricky task

Answer (score 1):

You note that you've installed the style file `processkv.sty` (and the other files of the `sauerj` package as well?) in the directory `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex[/sauerj]`, as per the instructions, and that you've run `texhash`, but that your TeX distribution can't find the file.

The style files `processkv` and `parcolumns` are parts of the `sauerj` package. The `sauerj` package -- or, at the very least, its documentation -- does not seem to have been updated significantly since late 2004. In the meantime, though, `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/` is no longer the root directory of the current TeXLive distribution. Hence, even if you ran `texhash`, your TeX distribution wouldn't notice the newly created style file(s).

Where exactly the the root of your TeX distribution is located will vary from system to system. E.g., if you're running TeXLive 2011, the root might be at `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist`.

Just install the style files somewhere in the correct directory tree -- say, at `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sauerj` or at `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/sauerj` -- and run `texhash`, and you should be in business. An advantage of placing the files of the `sauerj` package in the `texmf-local` directory is that you won't have to re-install it after TeXLive2012 is installed on your system.